# UK Standard Visitor visa

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas, applications

I am an Indian citizen and studying in Canada. I am applying for a UK standard visitor visa from Canada.

In the question which asks the details of my last ten years' travel history, I chose that I visited Canada, but then it asks how long you visited. As I am still in Canada, what should I answer? If I leave it blank, it indicates that I must put some time unit in there.

Comment: Do the form has a *Current* option?

Comment: I would put just how much time you were (at time of the filling of the form). And probably it doesn't matter much: you are applying from a third country, so the reason of such non-usual case (so your study) is known.

Comment: No the form doesnt have any current option. it just says to choose between days weeks months and years and a number corresponding to it.